# scp autocompletion displays websites as well as file names

Tags: scp

When using autocompletion it reveals web sites and file names.

So if i type `scp goo` and then type the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key it displays

```
gooey.zip goo.freelogs.com: googleads.g.doubleclick.net: google.tucows.com:
googleads2.g.doubleclick.net:  google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb   googlus.com:
googleadsense.ya.com:
```

The question is, where does it get these web sites from in the autocomplation process. I know the gooey.zip file is obviously a file in my directory, but where are the web sites coming from?

PS: I have uninstalled Zeitgeist if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got it from names of files in current directory, `/etc/hosts` file, `~/.ssh/config` file and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Check the script `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/scp` from package `bash-completion`.

Comment: Thanks, I had an entry of sexybabesx.com and was wondering where it came from, now I know, the host file, I have a host block file with all of the bogus sites so they don't come up.